# matplotlib y tkinter graficar lectura de sensor en tiempo real

Tags: python, matplotlib, raspberry-pi

Estoy graficando el flujo de aire con un sensor sensirion smf3000 con arduino uno, recibiendo los datos en una Raspberry Pi 4 y el código lo tengo en python usando las librerías matplotlib y tkinter, el flujo lo modifico a través de un ventilador alimentado por una fuente de poder y arduino uno y modificando dicho flujo con un slider en python.

La grafica recaba los datos del sensor fielmente, es decir, los datos que manda el sensor soncorrectos y se muestran en la gráfica.

Todo va bien hasta que:

1.-Al inicio del programa, cuando subo la velocidad del ventilador, este tarda en responder alrededor de 3 segundos(pero aún asi logro graficarlo)

2.-Tarda en responder la gráfica, es decir subo la velocidad del ventilador y tarda en reflejarse en la grafica al rededor de 2 segundos,lo que requiero es que la grafica responda inmediatamente cada que cambia el flujo.¿A que se debe el delay? ¿Por qué tarda en graficarse?

Intenté subir las fotos de las conexiones pero estan muy pesadas las rechaza el foro.

Este es el código en Arduino Uno:

```
#include <Wire.h>


void setup(){
 Wire.begin();
 Serial.begin(9600);
 int a = 0;
 int b = 0;
 int c = 0; 

 delay(1000);

Wire.beginTransmission(byte(0x40)); // transmit to device #064 (0x40)
Wire.write(byte(0x10));      //
Wire.write(byte(0x00));      //
Wire.endTransmission(); 

delay(5);

Wire.requestFrom(0x40, 3); //
a = Wire.read(); // first received byte stored here
b = Wire.read(); // second received byte stored here
c = Wire.read(); // third received byte stored here
Wire.endTransmission();
Serial.print(a);
Serial.print(b);
Serial.println(c);

delay(5);

Wire.requestFrom(0x40, 3); //
a = Wire.read(); // first received byte stored here
b = Wire.read(); // second received byte stored here
c = Wire.read(); // third received byte stored here
Wire.endTransmission();
Serial.print(a);
Serial.print(b);
Serial.println(c);
//delay(5);
delay(200);

}

uint8_t crc8(const uint8_t data, uint8_t crc) {
   crc ^= data;
    for ( uint8_t i = 8; i; --i ) {
    crc = ( crc & 0x80 )
       ? (crc << 1) ^ 0x31
       : (crc << 1);
    }
    return crc;
 }

void loop() {

 int offset = 32000; // Offset for the sensor
 float scale = 140.0; // Scale factor for Air and N2 is 140.0, O2 is 142.8


 Wire.requestFrom(0x40, 3); // read 3 bytes from device with address 0x40

 uint16_t a = Wire.read(); // first received byte stored here. The variable "uint16_t" can hold 2 bytes, this will be relevant later

 uint8_t b = Wire.read(); // second received byte stored here 

 uint8_t crc = Wire.read(); // crc value stored here 

 uint8_t mycrc = 0xFF; // initialize crc variable
 mycrc = crc8(a, mycrc); // let first byte through CRC calculation
 mycrc = crc8(b, mycrc); // and the second byte too
 if (mycrc != crc) { // check if the calculated and the received CRC byte matches
  
 //Serial.println("Error: wrong CRC");
 }
 
 a = (a << 8) | b; // combine the two received bytes to a 16bit integer value
 // a >>= 2; // remove the two least significant bits
 // float Flow = ((float)a - offset) / scale;
 //float Flow = (0.01*(float)a)-318.67;
 float lectura=(float)a;
 float Flow = (0.01*lectura)-319.42;

 //Serial.println(a); // print the raw data from the sensor to the serial interface
 Serial.println(Flow); // print the calculated flow to the serial interface

 delay(100);
}
```

Este es el código en Python:

```
from tkinter import *
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib import style
import serial as ser
import time
from PIL import ImageTk,Image
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider
import argparse
import sys
import requests
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(32,GPIO.OUT)

pin32 = GPIO.PWM(32,100)
pin32.start(0)

global condicion, data
flujo = 0
ciclo=0

data = np.array([])
condicion = False

viejo_dato = 0

#plot data
def plot_data():
    global data

    if(condicion == True):

        a = s.readline()
        a.decode()
        flujo = a.decode()
        lbvalorTemperatura = Label(fValores, text= flujo + "    ", bg="gray", fg="blue", font=("Times New Roman", 10)).place(x=135, y= 40)
   

        if len(data) < 10:
            data = np.append(data, float(a[0:4]))
        else:
            data[0:9] = data[1:10]
            data[9] = float(a[0:4])
        lines.set_xdata(np.arange(0,len(data)))
        lines.set_ydata(data)
    
        canvas.draw()
    
        #le mandamos el flujo para validar
        validar(flujo)
    
        #print(flujo)
    raiz.after(1, plot_data)
##
def plot_Iniciar():
    global condicion, Slider_control
    condicion = True
    s.reset_input_buffer()

##
def plot_Detener():
    global condicion
    condicion = False
    pin32.ChangeDutyCycle(int(0))

# creamos la ventana principal
raiz = Tk()

raiz.title("Respirador")
raiz.geometry("850x420")
raiz.config(bg="gray")

# w =raiz.winfo_screenwidth()
# h =raiz.winfo_screenheight()
# 
# raiz.geometry("%dx%d" % (w, h))

#agregamos los frames

frame1 = Frame(raiz)
frame1.grid(row=0, column=0)
frame1.config(bg="gray")
frame1.config(width="520", height="335")

contenedor = Frame(raiz)
contenedor.grid(row=0, column=1)
contenedor.config(bg="red")
contenedor.config(width="220", height="400")


fValores = Frame(contenedor)
fValores.grid(row=0, column=0)
fValores.config(bg="gray", highlightbackground="black", highlightthicknes=1)
fValores.config(width="320", height="130")

lbTemperatura = Label(fValores, text= "TEMPERATURA:", bg="gray", fg="white", font=("Times New Roman", 12) ).place(x=70, y=15)
#lbvalorTemperatura = Label(fValores, text="", bg="gray", fg="blue", font=("Times New Roman", 10)).place(x=70 y= 40)

lbOxigeno = Label(fValores, text= "NIVEL DE OXIGENO:", bg="gray", 
fg="white", font=("Times New Roman", 12)).place(x=50, y=85)
lbvalorOxigeno = Label(fValores, text="", bg="gray", fg="blue", font=("Times New Roman", 10)).place(x=135, y= 85)

ffoto = Frame(contenedor)
ffoto.grid(row=1, column=0)
ffoto.config(bg="gray", highlightbackground="black", highlightthicknes=1)
ffoto.config(width="320", height="130")

foto_paciente = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("perfil.png"))

lbFoto = Label(ffoto, image = foto_paciente).place(x=15, y=15)


lbNombre = Label(ffoto, text="Nombre: ", bg="gray", fg="white", font=("Times New Roman", 10)).place(x=145, y=12)
lbEdad = Label(ffoto, text="Edad: ", bg="gray", fg="white", font=("Times New Roman", 10)).place(x=145, y=37)
lbSexo = Label(ffoto, text="Sexo: ", bg="gray", fg="white", font=("Times New Roman", 10)).place(x=145, y=62)
lbUnidad = Label(ffoto, text="Unidad: ", bg="gray", fg="white", font=("Times New Roman", 10)).place(x=145, y=87)
lbfFolio = Label(ffoto, text="Folio: ", bg="gray", fg="white", font=("Times New Roman", 10)).place(x=145, y=112)

# valores del paciente

lbNombre_valor = Label(ffoto, text="valor", bg="gray", fg="blue", font= ("Times New Roman", 10)).place(x=195, y=12)
lbEdad_valor = Label(ffoto, text="valor", bg="gray", fg="blue", font=("Times New Roman", 10)).place(x=185, y=37)
lbSexo_valor = Label(ffoto, text="valor", bg="gray", fg="blue", font=("Times New Roman", 10)).place(x=185, y=62)
lbUnidad_valor = Label(ffoto, text="valor", bg="gray", fg="blue", font=("Times New Roman", 10)).place(x=195, y=87)
lbfFolio_valor = Label(ffoto, text="valor", bg="gray", fg="blue", font=("Times New Roman", 10)).place(x=185, y=112)

#control de escala

fControlador = Frame(contenedor)
fControlador.grid(row=2, column=0)
fControlador.config(bg="gray", highlightbackground="black", 
highlightthicknes=1)
fControlador.config(width="320", height="150")

lbControl = Label(fControlador, text="Nivel de Flujo: ", bg="gray",fg="white", font=("Times New Roman", 18)).place(x=30, y=3)

def getFlujo(val):
    global ciclo, Slider_Control
    #print(val)
    lbvalorOxigeno = Label(fValores, text=val, bg="gray", fg="blue", font=("Digital", 15)).place(x=135, y= 110)
    ciclo= val
    pin32.ChangeDutyCycle(int(ciclo))



Slider_control = Scale(fControlador, from_=0, to=99, length=200,
                   resolution=1, orient=HORIZONTAL,
                   command=getFlujo,
                   tickinterval = 20,
                   fg = 'white',
                   bg = 'black').place(x=40, y=55)


#eventos de la ventana

def cerrar_ventana():
    raiz.destroy()

raiz.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", cerrar_ventana)


#creamos la grafica
style.use("dark_background")
fig = Figure();
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.set_title('FLUJO')
ax.set_xlabel("Tiempo")
ax.set_ylabel("Nivel de flujo")
ax.set_xlim(0, 10)
ax.set_ylim(-150, 150)
lines = ax.plot([],[])[0]

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master = frame1)
canvas.get_tk_widget().place(x=5, y =0, width= 500, height = 280)
canvas.draw()

#creamos los botones

raiz.update();

btnIniciar = Button(raiz, text = "Iniciar", font = ('calibri', 12),
              command = lambda: plot_Iniciar())

btnIniciar.place(x=150, y=350)


raiz.update();

btnDetener = Button(raiz, text = "Detener", font = ('calibri', 12),
              command = lambda: plot_Detener())

btnDetener.place(x=btnIniciar.winfo_x()+btnIniciar.winfo_reqwidth() + 80, y = 350)



def validar(dato):
 
    global viejo_dato

    nuevo_dato = dato

    res_resta = float(nuevo_dato) - float(viejo_dato)

    print("viejo: " + str(viejo_dato) + " nuevo:" + str(nuevo_dato) + " resta: "+ str(res_resta))

    viejo_dato = nuevo_dato

    # > <

    if(res_resta > 0.3):
        inspirar()
    elif(res_resta < 0.3):
        exhalar()
    
# def inspirar():
#     global Slider_control, ciclo
#     ciclo= 99
#     print("estoy inspirando")
#     pin32.ChangeDutyCycle(int(ciclo))
# 
# def exhalar():
#     global Slider_control, ciclo
#     ciclo= 15
#     print("estoy exhalando")
#     pin32.ChangeDutyCycle(int(ciclo))

###iniciar la conexion serial
s = ser.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)
s.reset_input_buffer()

raiz.after(1, plot_data)
raiz.mainloop()
```

¿Cómo puedo graficar los datos verdaderamente en tiempo real, sin delays?